# How can I choose a specific track in Adobe Premier Editor panel?

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

There are several tracks in the Editor panel. I would like to choose one of the tracks and delete it. Is there any method such as a shortcut or button that I can use to do it easily?

How can I choose a specific track?

Comment: Hi - you need to add a lot more detail - exactly what are you trying to do, and what's going wrong?

Comment: There have several tracks in the Editory panel. Then, I would like to choose one of the track and delete it. Is there have any method such as  shortcut or button that I can do it easily?